# Converting a list of strings to a list of floats

Tags: python

Given a list of strings

```
['2.13', '4.67', '-6.1']
```

is there a way to convert this list into a list of floats?

Comment: convert it when you read it from the file using the `float` function

Comment: Also you can iterate directly on the `filehandle` to go over the file line-by-line. You should be sure to check for if the line is empty as well, because may programs will end the file with a blank line.

Comment: `list(map(float, list_of_strings))`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert strings into floats using `float(string_value)`.

```py
>>> value = '3.14159'
>>> float(value)
3.14159
```

Edit: some more info:

Note that if `string_value` is not a valid float, Python will raise a `ValueError`:

```py
>>> value = 'not a float'
>>> float(value)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'not a float'
```

So if there's a chance your file has invalid values in it, it may be worth doing:

```py
try:
    float_value = float(value)
except ValueError:
    # Handle errors here
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my_float_list = list(map(float, ['2.13', '4.67', '-6.1']))
```

Relevant docs:

1. [map](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map)
2. [float](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#float)
3. [list](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#list)

Answer (score -2):

Try this simple loop:

```
my_string_list = ['2.13', '4.67', '-6.1']
my_float_list = []
for item in my_string_list:
    my_float_list.append(float(item))
```